# Google maps and places sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, sidebar

I 'm beginer to js and coding and i trying build an web site with google map + places api, so when type "restaurant or bar or etc" to shw this business on map and on sidebar.

http://jsbin.com/ayugun/46/edit

All code works fine without sidebar code:

```
var side_bar_html = "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers["+parseInt(gmarkers.length-1)+"],\"click\");'>"+place.name+"</a><br>";
     document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += side_bar_html;
```

but I need to repair this code to make it workable.
So when I type" restaurant or bars or etc." to show me on map and on #side_bar

WHere is error in my code for sidebar?

sorry for my englsih, is not very well, but I learn hard to learn english and coding.thanks

Comment: here is a working version but without sidebar http://jsbin.com/ayugun/48/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gmarkers` variable is undefined. It simply does not reach part of appending it to the 'side_bar'.

Also, why not to do this such way?

```
 var sideClick = jQuery("<a class=side_click href='#'></a>");
 $(sideClick).html(place.name);
 $("#side_bar").append(sideClick);
 $(sideClick).on("click", function() {
     google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[parseInt(gmarkers.length-1)], "click");
 });
```

The problem with your initial code - it can not access the `place` variable (besides the fact that `javascript:` is kind of bad practice). So, by putting it all into callback for `google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {..}` it now can access `place` variable and get `name` value of current looping `place`.

I am still not sure what is with `gmarkers` (maybe, it should be `markers` (misspeling)?). It did not declared anywhere.

Here is working version (without `gmarkers` part, it is still broken): http://jsbin.com/ayugun/54/

You may like to discover more about closures in JavaScript:
[Good answers about it on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).
[Material from Google docs for the Maps.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) (the part under **Using Closures in Event Listeners** header). This example is related to the Google Maps and great for showing what is closure in real life.

Comment: thanks, but when I click on sidebar link wont open infowindow (modalbox) ?

Comment: also when I type new search, sidebar links not changed, why that?

Comment: 1) Take a look at the code - on callback it executes "google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[parseInt(gmarkers.length-1)], "click");". Which is still broken. I have no idea what `gmarkers` is - it is undefined. You have to figure out what variable you want to pass.
2) What do you mean? It works for me in Chrome and Firefox, it adds new links to the sidebar when new search was performed. I just show working closure, you are free to bend the rules as you want - `empty()` sidebar on changes and whatever.

Comment: yes, on chaneges sidebar must be pulled with new links, and also when i click on sidebar links won't to open infowindow in map ?

Comment: i dont know what is the gmarkers, becouse I copy this part of code from an exmple

Comment: I am sorry, but this is a very bad attitude to problem solving - I recommend you to read documentation and to actually understand code you copying next time. What you asked for is bug-hunting and feature implementing, not helping, it is disliked usually. Anyway, here is the working version http://jsbin.com/ayugun/57/ you can review the code.

Comment: very very thanks, I will show you what aplication will do with this code. thanks so much, you are the best!

Comment: Why when I type etx. "Paris, France" with autosuggestion, don't find anything, just map zoom on some other place?